# Audio File conversion format, bitrate- from wav to aac

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio file with the following properties.

**File Name   :   A.wav**

**Format: WAV**

**Type : PCM 32 bit floating little endian**

**Bitrate : 2048 kbps**

**Frequency:32000 Khz**

**Channels : 2**

I want to convert the above file to this format.

**Format: AAC**

**Type : Advance audio encoding**

**Bitrate : 384 kbps**

**Frequency:32000 Khz**

**Channels : 2**

I have been experimenting with ffmpeg but unsuccessful.

```
ffmpeg -i A.wav -acodec aac -ab 384k B.aac
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The native encoder is VBR and maxes out at around 260 kbps for stereo.

Comment: Well I have a file right here that says its AAC format and its 384kbps. The max i cna get is 315kbps form ffmpeg tool. I am using SPEK tool to see file formats.